# PersistenceProvider createEntityManagerFactory returns null in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipselink

I created a standalone app to access my database (either mssql or h2)
i created a helper class which connects to my server by passing the connection details.

all fine and works as it is supposed to be.

now i move my code to an Eclipse Plugin (->OSGi)
first i ran into a Driver Not Found Error, but i fixed this with passing my ClassLoader to the PersistenceProvider.

now i got the next problem, which i am not able to resolve:
the PersistenceProvider returns **null**, when i call **createEntityManagerFactory** passing the persistence unit name and my map.

it does not throw any exceptions...simply returns **null**

so i guess the driver is found...
as the standalone application is working, it can't be the persistence.xml either...

any ideas?

here my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="EclipseLinkTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<!--   <mapping-file>META-INF/contact-orm.xml</mapping-file>     -->
    <properties>
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:D:/JAVA/Final/lumo.osgi.service.eclipselink.impl/db/embedded.db" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" /> -->

<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://dbserverIP:1433;DatabaseName=testsystem" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="editor" /> -->
<!--       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="editorpwd" /> -->


      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
<!--       <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> -->
<!--       <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" /> -->
<!--       <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" /> -->
<!--       <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/> -->
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is the code to get the configuration (application is the main class - so its class loader got information about everything in my target definition)

```
public Properties getEmbeddedConfiguration(String path, String database,
            String login, String password) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // this one is for getting started in OSGi & JPA

        // No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:file:C:\temp\Thumbs.db;IFEXISTS=TRUE
//      props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CLASSLOADER,
//              EclipseLinkServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader());
        // this fixes the driver not found but leaves a nullpointer
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CLASSLOADER,
                Application.class.getClassLoader());

         String connectionString = String.format(
         "jdbc:h2:file:%s%s;IFEXISTS=TRUE", path, database);
         props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
         props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", connectionString);
         props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", login);
         props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);

         props.put("eclipselink.target-database",
         "org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform");
         props.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "drop-and-create-tables");
         props.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
        return props;
    }
```

and last but not least the create part

```
PersistenceProvider p = new PersistenceProvider();
factory = p.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME,
getEmbeddedConfiguration(folder, database, username, pwd));
System.out.println("factory: " + factory);
em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: We can't help unless you show your code, and persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

To get JPA running in OSGi take a look at the [Gemini project](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/jpa/)

Comment: thats what i do right now, but i got problems that the ConfigurationAdmin Service is not starting...

Comment: You should not have to fiddle with the classloader.  Do you have the correct MANIFEST.MF entries such as `JPA-PersistenceUnits: MyPu`, where "MyPu" is your persistence unit name?

Comment: i got the problem with configurationAdmin solved now, its starting in my test application. the persistence.xml is coorect as i can connect to my database from the example
i try to move it to my real application and i do not even get the basic example working, the ServiceTracker never adds a service although i get the log on console that it Begins predeploying Persistence Unit